# Post requests timeout but Get requests get through

Tags: node.js, firebase, docker, google-cloud-run, hapi.js

I'm deploying a frontend website using Firebase hosting and a nodejs backend APIs using cloud run hosted container.

I'm using Firebase rewrite to redirect all API calls to the cloud run service so that I can access APIs from mydomain.com/api/****

```
"rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/api/**",
        "run": {
          "serviceId": "*****",
          "region": "******"
        }
     }
],
```

I'm using Hapi js framework and I set cors open to all origins in the server configuration

```
routes : {
    cors  : { origin: ["*"] },
}
```

When I make a Get call to test routes like `/api/ping` and `/api/check/{id}` locally (local container on windows), using google assigned URL to the hosted container or using the custom domain associated to firebase hosting, I get 200 response as expected.

When I try a POST to `/api/contact`, I get a connection timeout or 502 Bad Gateway from Firebase (timeout limited to 60s).

I don't understand why it does not even work with the container I run locally ? When I run the nodejs app, the POST APIs are responding fine. Why Gets and not Posts ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you put some debug statements to see if the call is reaching the backend?

Comment: Well it's a hapi js bug. I have node 12 at my station and I was using node 16 in the container. Hapi js response is set to null with node 16. I switched the node version to 12 and everything is running fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Hapi.js (HttpAPI) Bug, with Node.js Version 16.

As mentioned by @Lemalach, the workstation code was on Node.js 12 and the container was on Node.js 16 version.

Hapi.js response is set to null with Node.js 16.

Switching to Node.js 12 solves the issue.